# Cycle through months until month is displayed c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Edit - Ok i have calender structured as below

```
< September 2016 >
```

Now i want to specify a month (January 2016) and have it click the right arrow till January 2016 appears

Now the element is structured as below

```
<div class="calendar">
<h3 id="calendar-month" class="calendar-title" title="September 2016"        
role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">September 2016</h3>
<table class="calendar-grid" role="grid" aria-labelledby="calendar-month">
```

I tried the code below, but it didnt work (NB i havent used the method to click the next month in this example)

```
         public static void MonthOut(string month)
    {
        var nextMnthOutBtn = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@title='Go to the next month']"));
        var calMonth = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("calendar"));

        IList<IWebElement> allValidDates = calMonth.FindElements(By.Id("calendar-month"));

        foreach (var date in allValidDates)
            if (date.Text.Equals(month))
            {
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: What month do you want displayed as default?

Comment: The default month is the current month.. So i wan to specify January. It goes to the page. Ignore the currently displayed month (unless it matches what i have specified) and then start clicking next month arrow until January appears and then it stops

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.

1. I would start by seeing if there is a way that you can jump to the correct month. Look at the URL and see if there are parameters that you can set, e.g. `...?month=9&year=2016` or something like that. If so and it's within your requirements, then use that method. It will be much, much faster.
2. If you can't do #1, I would write a function kinda like you did but take in a `DateTime` parameter for the `targetDate` (you need month *and* year). Compare the month/year on the page to the target date and determine if you need to click right to +1 month or click left to -1 month. Keep doing that until the current month/year = the target month/year. Some sample code for the function is below.

   ```
   public static void ChangeCalendarMonth(DateTime targetDate)
   {
       By currentDateLocator = By.Id("calendar-month");
       By leftArrowLocator = By.Id("some locator");
       By rightArrowLocator = By.Id("some locator");

       // read current calendar date from page
       DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Parse(Driver.FindElement(currentDateLocator).Text);
       int compare = DateTime.Compare(currentDate, targetDate);
       while (compare != 0)
       {
           if (compare < 0)
           {
               // click right to +1 month
               Driver.FindElement(rightArrowLocator).Click();
           }
           else
           {
               // click left arrow to -1 month
               Driver.FindElement(leftArrowLocator).Click();
           }

           // read current calendar date from page
           currentDate = DateTime.Parse(Driver.FindElement(currentDateLocator).Text);
           compare = DateTime.Compare(currentDate, targetDate);
       }
   }
   ```

and then you would call it like

```
DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1); // January 2017
ChangeCalendarMonth(targetDate);
```

NOTE: You will want to make sure that you always create the `targetDate`'s day as 1. When you grab the month/year off the page and convert it to `DateTime` it will always be Day 1. If you don't have them both as Day 1, you will end up in an endless loop.